# '$R$-rational points,' where $R$ is an arbitrary ring

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, affine-schemes

On page 49 of Liu's *Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves*, we find Example 3.32. In it, he shows that if $k$ is a field and $X=k[T_1,\dots,T_n]/I$ is an affine scheme over $k$, the sections $X(k)$ (the $k$-rational points of $X$) are in bijection with the algebraic set $Z(I)$ cut out by $I$. This is the set of all $\alpha\in k^n$ with $P(\alpha)=0$ for every $P(T)\in I$.

At the end of the section, he gives this exercise:

> $\textbf{3.6}$ Generalize Example 3.32 to the case where $k$ is an
>   arbitrary ring.

How is this possible? The proof in the example makes essential use of the fact that $k$ is a field. Clearly we want to consider the set cut out by $I$ over $R^n$, where $R$ is some ring, and relate this to the sections $X(R)$, but I do not see how to proceed. In particular, the proof identified the $k$-rational points with the points where the residue field was $k$. Since the residue field is always a field, but $R$ may not be, we can no longer use the residue field to identify the $R$-rational points.

Comment: You spread your hands about *yea* far apart and then you start waving them about in circles...

Comment: I've known a few authors who have ridiculous things as exercises. My favorites so far are (paraphrased): "invent the Dorroh extension" and "Prove the [Cartan-Brauer-Hua theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartan%E2%80%93Brauer%E2%80%93Hua_theorem)."

Comment: @rschwieb Where can I find those? You have piqued my curiosity...

Comment: The results or the exercises?! Martin Isaacs assigned the first one, and Nathan Jacobson assigned the latter one.

Comment: @rschwieb The exercises of course!

Comment: Isaacs Graduate Algebra problem 12.4 page 172, and Jacobson's Basic algebra I problem 10 page 100. I don't know why you're interested: I think these problems are perfect examples of bad problems precisely because they are prohibitively open ended.

Comment: @rschwieb: I agree with your assessment of them - but that's exactly why I'd want concrete references to point to :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $X = \text{Spec}\,A$ be an affine scheme of finite type over $R$. Then $X$ comes with a map $X\rightarrow \text{Spec}\,R$ so that the corresponding map of rings $R\rightarrow A$ makes $A$ a finitely generated $R$-algebra. So we can write $A \cong R[T_1,\dots,T_n]/I$ for some ideal $I$.

Now $X(R)$, the $R$-points of $X$, are maps $\text{Spec}\,R \rightarrow X$ which are sections of the map $X \rightarrow \text{Spec}\,R$. Since we're talking about maps of affine schemes, these are in canonical bijection with ring maps $A \rightarrow R$ which are sections of the structure map $R\rightarrow A$, that is, $R$-algebra homomorphisms $R[T_1,\dots,T_n]/I\rightarrow R$.

Now since $R[T_1,\dots,T_n]$ is the free $R$-algebra on $n$ generators,

\begin{align}
\text{Hom}_R(R[T_1,\dots,T_n]/I,R) &\cong \{f\in\text{Hom}_R(R[T_1,\dots,T_n],R)\,|\,I\subseteq \text{Ker}(f)\}\\
&\cong \{(r_1,\dots,r_n)\in R^n\,|\,p(r_1,\dots,r_n) = 0\,\text{for all}\,p\in I\}.
\end{align}

Comment: We seem to have posted at the same time, but I like your answer better =D

Comment: Thanks! The answers are more or less the same, mine is just a bit more verbose. Of course, in your answer $R$ should be a $k$-algebra...

Comment: Yes, but that edit button is so far away...

Comment: Why is $X(R)$ in canonical bijection with $R$-algebra homomorphisms $R[T_1,\ldots,T_n]/I\to R$? I know that the map $\rho: \operatorname{Mor}(\operatorname{Spec}R,X)\to\operatorname{Hom}_\text{rings}(R[T_1,\ldots,T_n]/I,R), (\sigma, \sigma^\#)\mapsto \sigma^\#(X)$ is bijective. I also proved that $\rho(X(R))\subseteq\operatorname{Hom}_\text{algebra}(R[T_1,\ldots,T_n]/I,R)$. But I can't prove the opposite inclusion.

Comment: In my above comment, $\operatorname{Mor}(\operatorname{Spec} R, X)$ is the set of all morphisms of scheme from $\operatorname{Spec} R$ to $X$, $\operatorname{Hom}_\text{rings}(R[T_1,\ldots,T_n]/I,R)$ is the set of all ring homomorphisms from $R[T_1,\ldots,T_n]/I$ to $R$, and $\operatorname{Hom}_\text{algebra}(R[T_1,\ldots,T_n]/I,R)$ is the set of all algebra homomorphisms from $R[T_1,\ldots,T_n]/I$ to $R$.

Comment: @zxcv Suppose $A$ is an $R$-algebra with structure map $\rho\colon R\to A$. Then an $R$-algebra morphism $A\to R$ is a ring homomorphism $f\colon A\to R$ such that $f\circ \rho = \text{id}_R$ (do you agree?).

Answer (score 2):

Let $Y=$ Spec $R$. The $R$-valued points of $X$, $\hspace{1mm} X(R)$, are the elements of Hom$(Y,X)$, which are in bijection with Hom$(k[T_1,\ldots,T_n]/I,R)$. Thus, $X(R)$ is in bijection with the tuples $\alpha=(a_1,\ldots,a_n) \in R^n$ for which $P(\alpha)=0$ for all $P \in I$.

Comment: However, when $R$ is a field, this is not to be confused with the notion of $R$-rational points...

Comment: @ZhenLin: Dear Zhen, I don't understand your comment.  These are precisely the $R$-rational points.  Regards,